# how to change the keyboard backlight timeout in Ubuntu OS for HP Pavilion Laptop

Tags: linux, laptop, keyboard, hp-pavilion, backlight

I have a HP Pavilion 15-bc513TX 2019 laptop. The keyboard backlight goes out after a few minutes in the dark.

How can I change the keyboard backlight settings for my computer running Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Making assumptions here without knowing your laptop model, but you can try the following:

**cd into the directory in /sys that has the setting**

```
cd "$(find /sys/devices/platform/ -name '*kbd_backlight')"
```

**then change the timeout (*bash* specific)** (example below assumes 10s and changes it to 12hrs)

```
sudo tee stop_timeout <<< '43200s'
```

if you are not using a bash shell, then you should do the following, which is a more portable method:

```
echo 43200s | sudo tee stop_timeout
```

Comment: Few quirks not addressed by the answer, yet worth explaining: (1) `<<<` is a bashism (works in Bash but not in other shells in general). The portable way is `echo 43200s | sudo tee stop_timeout`. This somewhat cumbersome syntax is needed because `sudo echo 43200s > stop_timeout` [won't work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1416/108618), unless you run it in a root's shell. (2) It may be that `stop_timeout` accepts only few predefined values. Even if the command succeeds, you'd like to `cat stop_timeout` and confirm the desired value is there.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski you should consider expanding that out to a full answer.

Comment: @Burgi I will rather edit this answer if the author doesn't improve it first. IMO there's no need to create another answer with the same *core* (`*kbd_backlight` and `stop_timeout`). And I'm not really convinced the core applies to HP. I have found `foo::kbd_backlight` for `foo` being `asus`, `dell`, `toshiba`, but not `hp` or so.

Comment: this works on my `Dell XPS 15 9560`